# Probability of picking out coloured balls of different colours

Tags: probability

I am stuck on a question. I know how to attempt it but I was wondering if there is an easier way to do it.

**Question**
Suppose you have one red ball, one green ball, one blue ball, and three white balls. Three balls are drawn at random without replacement. What is the probability that the drawn balls are of different colours

**How I think of it**: To do this, I would try to find the probability of all the different cases. Such as case where the balls are drawn in this pattern: RGB, RBG, RBW...etc but as you can see this will get too long and time consuming.

Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{6}{3}$ equally likely ways to pick $3$ balls from $6$.

To count the ways in which the colours are all different, there is RGB ($1$ way) plus the ways that involve white.

To count these, the non-whites can be chosen in $\binom{3}{2}$ ways, and for each choice the whites can be chosen in $\binom{3}{1}$ ways.

Thus our probability is $\dfrac{1+\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{6}{3}}$. This simplifies nicely.

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for showing me an easier way to do this! it indeed simplifies nicely!

Comment: You are welcome. A similar approach will take care of situations where there are more than one red, blue, and/or green.

Answer (score 1):

The probability of picking balls all of which are different in colour is equal to the probability of picking not more than one white ball.

The only way to get two balls of the same colour is to pick more than $1$ white ball.

Say $A$ is the event such that exactly $2$ of the chosen balls are white and $B$ is the event of picking all $3$ white balls.

$$P(A) =  \frac {\binom{3}{2}\binom{3}{1}} {\binom{6}{3}}$$ and $$P(B) =  \frac {\binom{3}{3}} {\binom{6}{3}} $$

Your required probability is equal to $1 - [P(A) + P(B)]$